# how to declare a member of a class type defined in a different file

Tags: c++, struct, member

I have a header file in which I have defined a struct. I want an instance of this struct to be a member of a class that is defined in a different file. How do I do it?

Comment: You want the struct to be a nested class in another type? Or you want an _instance_ of the struct as a data member in another type?

Comment: I want instance of the struct as a data member in another type

Comment: Then Erik's answer is correct. I suggest reading a good C++ book! I have edited your question to clarify it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`#include` the header containing the struct in the header where you define the class.

Foo.h:

```
struct Foo {
};
```

Bar.h:

```
#include "Foo.h"
class Bar {
  Foo f;
};
```

Comment: Thank you! Also, I have function declared in the same Foo.h (and implemented in Foo.c)and I am calling that function in class Bar. I'm getting a link error(Symbol(s) not found). What should I do?

Comment: @Namratha: Guessing that you use gcc: `g++ -Wall -o myapp Foo.c Bar.c Otherfiles.c`

Comment: I am doing it in XCode on the MAC actually. I was wondering if there's something that I should do in the code.

Comment: @Namratha: You get symbol not found errors for two primary reasons: 1) You didn't actually implement something you declared and used, or 2) Your build doesn't link all your files together.

Comment: Actually, I had to use extern "C" which is used when a C++ compiler has to compile C code.